# Can a Cython array of unsigned chars contain a zero?

Tags: python, cython

I want to speed up some core routines in a Python project by using Cython (I am very new to both). I am writing augmenting .pxd files with type information for the corresponding .py's. In one .py I have a class, with an instance variable `array.array` that I want to be an array of unsigned chars in Cython. 
It compiles, but I found out (after painstaking debugging) that whenever a 0 is written somewhere in the array, its length changes, and an IndexError is raised if the array is accessed beyond the 0 element.

Here is a small (not sure it's minimal) example.

ram.py:

```
import array

class Ram:

def __init__(self):
    self.ram = array.array('B', [1,1,0,1,1])
    print(len(self.ram))
```

ram.pxd:

```
cdef class Ram:
    cdef unsigned char[5] ram
```

What I get after compiling into an extension module:

```
>>> import ram
>>> ram.Ram()
2
```

I tried switching off bound checks with the compiler directive `boundscheck = False` but to no avail.

It works as expected (giving a length of 5) if I use `cdef unsigned int[5] ram` in ram.pxd, but I want to use an array of bytes.

How can I keep the length of my array fixed, while still being able to write 0s in it?

(I am using Cython 0.29.13 and Python 3.7.4)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is with `len` rather than the array. `len` is a Python function so isn't "really" defined for a char array. However Cython tries to provide an answer and defaults to the `strlen` approach of counting until the first 0 byte. In this case this is wrong, but it's a sensible general best guess.

You're fine to define an array like this, and to store any data, including `0`. You just can't rely on Cython's `len` to get the length - in this case the length is a constant so you know it, but if it were a dynamically allocated array *you'd* be responsible to storing it. You may also have to be careful of Cython's auto-conversion to a Python string too.

---

*Edit:* A little more detail since I don't think you're quite doing what you think you are:

```
cdef const char[5] ram
```

defines a C array of length 5. This is very space-efficient (it stores no extra data except the 5 characters), quick to access in Cython, but has no Python equivalent and therefore to access it in Python needs conversion (either automatic, or something you do yourself)

```
ram = array.array(...)
```

copies the Python array into the C array.

I suspect you should use a memoryview instead:

```
cdef unsigned char[::1] ram # ::1 specifies C contiguous
```

These are a little less space-efficient (they store some Python reference counting information and a shape), and are medium-quick to access in Cython (you can make them quicker by turning off bounds checking and negative indexing, and by specifying C contiguous as I've done here). More importantly for you they can be accessed in Python (although at regular Python speed), and Cython won't attempt to treat them as C strings.

```
ram = array.array(...)
```

creates a view of the data contained in the array (no copy - it shares the data).

Comment: Thank you @DavidW, this is helpful. I think my problem was twofold. One side is Python's `len`, which I now understand. The other side is probably related to what you mention about auto-conversion to Python string. What happens is that if I use `public` in the declaration of `ram` in the .pxd file, and I then access `Ram().ram[3]` from Python, I get an `IndexError: index out of range`. Is this due to the conversion to a null-terminated string?

Comment: @user3725511 - yes, I think the `cdef public` attribute is just converting treating it as a null-terminated string. I've edited a bit more detail into an edit - having re-read your question I don't think you're quite doing what you think, and you may find memoryviews a better approach